# diagonally subtract different columns in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create another column in dataframe which consists value of difference. The difference is calculated by subtracting different rows of different columns for unique date values.

I tried looking for various stackoverflow links but didn't find the answer.

The difference should be the value after subtracting value of ATA of 2st row with ATD of 1st row and so on for unique date values. For ex, ATA of 1st january cannot be subtracted from ATD of 2nd january.

For example:-
The difference column's first values should be NAN. 
Second values should be 50 Mins (17:13:00 - 16:23:00)
But ATD of 02-01-2019 should not be subtracted with ATA of 01-01-2019

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply a `shift` grouped by `Date` and then subtract this with `ATD`

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ATA':range(0,365),'ATD':range(10,375),'Date':pd.date_range(start="2018-01-01",end="2018-12-31")})
>>> df['ATD'] = df['ATD']/6.0
>>> df = pd.concat([df,df,df,df])
>>> df['shifted_ATA'] = df.groupby('Date')['ATA'].transform('shift')
>>> df['result'] = df['ATD'] - df['shifted_ATA']
>>> df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=[1])
>>> df.head(20)
   ATA       ATD       Date  shifted_ATA    result
0    0  1.666667 2018-01-01          NaN       NaN
0    0  1.666667 2018-01-01          0.0  1.666667
0    0  1.666667 2018-01-01          0.0  1.666667
0    0  1.666667 2018-01-01          0.0  1.666667
1    1  1.833333 2018-01-02          NaN       NaN
1    1  1.833333 2018-01-02          1.0  0.833333
1    1  1.833333 2018-01-02          1.0  0.833333
1    1  1.833333 2018-01-02          1.0  0.833333
2    2  2.000000 2018-01-03          2.0  0.000000
2    2  2.000000 2018-01-03          NaN       NaN
2    2  2.000000 2018-01-03          2.0  0.000000
2    2  2.000000 2018-01-03          2.0  0.000000
3    3  2.166667 2018-01-04          3.0 -0.833333
3    3  2.166667 2018-01-04          3.0 -0.833333
3    3  2.166667 2018-01-04          NaN       NaN
3    3  2.166667 2018-01-04          3.0 -0.833333
4    4  2.333333 2018-01-05          4.0 -1.666667
4    4  2.333333 2018-01-05          4.0 -1.666667
4    4  2.333333 2018-01-05          4.0 -1.666667
4    4  2.333333 2018-01-05          NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Gaurav can you help me please generalize this. There are not only 2 dates but the data is of 1 year.

Comment: This would work irrespective of the length of the time series as the group by happens on the `Date` column.

Comment: But what about the time, I actually wanted the difference diagonally

Comment: By diagonally subtracting A ( [a1,a2,a3,...,an] ) and B ([b1, b2, b3, ..., bn]) you mean a[i] - B[i-1] right? That is what shift is achieving. You did not share a reproducible dataset so i used incremental numeric values instead of dates